# Is it possible to get gVim to execute external commands in cygwin by default?

Tags: vim, cygwin, gvim, gvimrc

Is it possible to get gVim (on windows) to execute external commands in cygwin by default? i.e. !ps will open a cygwin terminal showing the currenty running processes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to tell Vim to run the **bash** program instead of **cmd.exe**, and bash needs to run as a login shell so that it will read the profile/login scripts and set up the environment (PATH, etc) properly.

You also need to change the setting that introduces command-line options to the shell:

```
:set shell=C:\Cygwin\bin\bash.exe\ -login
:set shellcmdflag=-c
```

If your cygwin commands require arguments, you should probably also

```
:set shellquote=\"
```

to ensure that the whole command gets wrapped up in quotes properly, otherwise the shell will only get the first word and ignore the rest.